# Pushing a View Controller moves its view up by 20 pixels in iOS 6?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios6, uinavigationcontroller

I have a navigation controller on which i am adding on a UIViewController in the following way

```
UINavigationController * navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.homeViewController];

_centerViewNavigaionController = navController;

if (bIsDeviceOSVersion7) {
    _centerViewNavigaionController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
}
else
{
 _centerViewNavigaionController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, -20, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height+20);
}

[self.view addSubview:navController.view];
[self addChildViewController:navController];
```

It is working fine in iOS 7 but in iOS6 - HomeViewController (i.e RootViewController of this navigation controller) loads fine. But when i push a new View Controller onto HomeViewController i.e RootViewController the new view frame moves up by 20 pixels only the fist time. Next time when its pushed it works fine. I looked up on stack overflow but not able to resolve this issue. How can i fix this?

Comment: set detla propery of view ie y = 20 in iOS 6 and  y = 0 in iOS7

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing this

_centerViewNavigaionController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, -20, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height+20);

you can just set the delta property through Interface Builder for the immediate view/views under viewcontroller object. or else you must use Autolayout to avoid such things.